# How to export report to .xls file from Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer v11

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, reporting

Tell me please, how can I export a report (rdlc) from ReportViewer (v.11) to .xls file?

This version of viewer could export to .xlsx file by click on Export -> Excel button. In this case SaveFileDialog would be open, and I can choose only xlsx format. But I need to save reports in .xls format too.

Sorry for my English - I just started to learn it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer. I put it here for another...

ReportViewer of 11'th version could to export report into .xls format, but, by default, this possibility is hidden.

A array of supporting export formats you can see using `ReportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()` instance method. But all properties of received elements are readonly (including `Visible`).

To change visibility of eleemnts you should to use a reflection. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set visibility of specified by name RenderingExtension to setted value
/// For example, name of Excel (.xls) extension is "Excel"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="reportViewer">Instance of ReportViewer control</param>
/// <param name="extensionName">Extension name (for example: "Excel")</param>
/// <param name="visible">Visibility</param>
private void SetVisibilityOnRenderingExtension(ReportViewer reportViewer, string extensionName, bool visible)
{
    var renderingExtension = reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == extensionName);

    if (renderingExtension != null)
    {
        FieldInfo info = renderingExtension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (info != null)
        {
            info.SetValue(renderingExtension, visible);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope, it helps someone :)